# Rails Many to Many issue with 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to implement a solution to manage Multiple Parent Customers for a given Customer.

e.g. I have a table called "Customer":

```
id int
name string
```

and another one called "Customer_Relationships":

```
id int
customer_id int          (this references the Customer table)
parent_customer_id int   (this also references the Customer table)
```

how do i design the model files so that i can get associations such as:

- all parents for a given customer_id
- all child customer rows for a given parent_customer_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a good post on this at (and it worked for me): http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through

What may work in your case is the following (for simplicity, it refers to everything as parent/children):

Relationship.rb:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Customer"
belongs_to :child, :class_name => "Customer"
```

Customer.rb:

```
has_many :parent_relationships, :foreign_key => "child_id", :class_name => "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :parents, :through => :parent_relationships

has_many :child_relationships, :foreign_key => "parent_id", :class_name => "Relationship", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :children, :through => :child_relationships
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_relationships
  has_many :parent_customers, through: :customer_relationships
  has_many :parent_relationships, class_name: "CustomerRelationship", foreign_key: "parent_customer_id"
  has_many :child_customers, through: :parent_relationships, source: :customer
end

class CustomerRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :parent_customer, class_name: "Customer"
end
```

With this setup, querying for all parents for a given customer_id looks like

```
Customer.find(customer_id).parent_customers
```

And getting all child Customer rows for a given parent_customer_id looks like

```
Customer.find(parent_customer_id).child_customers
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have most of it working, except for the part where I try to find all child Customer rows for a given parent customer id. So this query:
    
    `Customer.find(parent_customer_id).child_customers`

is not returning any data, just an empty array.

Comment: I put together the above from memory, so I probably missed an important bit. Can you post the SQL generated from `Customer.find(parent_customer_id).child_customers`?

Comment: The SQL query is:

`SELECT Customer .* 
FROM Customer  INNER JOIN Customer_Relationships 
ON Customer.id = Customer_Relationships.customer_id 
WHERE ((Customer_Relationships.customer_id = 5))`

i think the remaining issue is that the “WHERE” clause is using “customer_id” instead of using “parent_customer_id”…?